# Finding the basis of $\mathbb R^5/W.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help finding out the basis in the following question :

> Let $~~W=\big<[1~~2~~1~~0~~1]^t~,[1~~0~~1~~1~~1]^t~,[1~~2~~1~~3~~1]^t\big >~$  be a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$ .  Find a basis of $\mathbb R^5/W.$

I can't figure out the basis , kindly help with some hint on how to proceed ...

Comment: Sketch: Let's use $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ to denote your basis of $W$. Find vectors $v_{4}$ and $v_{5}$ such that $\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{5}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbf{R}^{5}$; the set $\{v_{4} + W, v_{5} + W\}$ is a basis of the quotient space.

Comment: @user86418 thanks for the sketch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i get when i row reduce the basis vector of $W$ together with the standard basis $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_5$ of $\mathbb R^5.$

$$\pmatrix{1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\2&0&2&0&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&\\0&1&3&0&0&0&1&0&\\1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1} \to 
 \pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0.33&0&-0.33&0.33\\0&1&0&0&-0.5&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0&0.16&0&0.33&-0.33\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&-1\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0&-1}$$

therefore a basis for $\mathbb R^5 \setminus W$ is $$\{(1,0,0,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,0,0)^T \}.$$

Comment: I can't get how are there 8 columns in your matrix , kindly explain..

Comment: there are eight columns in the matrix because of two things: (a) the last five columns is the standard basis for $R^5.$ (b) we will find the basis for $R^5\setminus W$ in the standard basis. you can see from the reduce matrix that only $e_1, e_3$ are linearly independent of the first three columns.

Comment: I'm unable to get the purpose behind your construction of matrix , what are we row-reducing , please help explaining...

Comment: i put the three basis vectors of $W$ in the first three columns of the $5 \times 8$ matrix and then filled it up with the standard basis. the purpose of row reducing is to figure out which of the standard basis are linear combination of the three basis vectors of $W.$ you can read that $e_2 = -0.33w_1 + 0.5 w_2 -0.16w_3$ and only $e_1, e_3$ are not in $W.$

Comment: @Pragya, you are welcome. linear algebra is fun.

Answer (score 1):

Row reduction of the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&x\\
2&0&2&y\\
1&1&1&z\\
0&1&3&t\\
1&1&1&u\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&x\\
0&1&3&t\\
0&0&6&y-2x+2t\\
0&0&0&z-x\\
0&0&0&u-x
\end{bmatrix}$$
shows $W$ has dimension $3$ and is defined by the equations $\,x=z=u,\,$ hence $\,\mathbf R^5/W\,$ has dimension $2$ and it is enough to find two linearly independent vectors that do not satisfy these equations, e.g.:
$$e_1={}^{\mathrm t}(1,0,0,0,0),\enspace e_2={}^{\mathrm t}(0,0,1,0,0) $$

Comment: Sir why you had choosen the fourth column? and from where it comes?